# Retaining symbology used in QGIS when building map in QGIS2web plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, maps, qgis2web

I am a GIS tech for a telco company, I build a lot of maps in QGIS and am always trying to find ways to share the map and its data with my workers.

When i build my map in QGIS and try to open QGIS2web, most of the symbology and just simply the text formating gets all ascew and i dont know why. I've tried using different symbols and changing the formatting but to no avail.

Here is the map in QGIS:

[image]

And here's the output in QGIS2Web:

[image]

the 1 and 2 you see are telephone poles I want people to be able to click and get the relevant information, but as it stands the icons or text i use simply doesn't show up.

Any advice you have with working with this tool , or offering an alternative is perfectly acceptable. the only clincher is that it needs to be able to work locally.

Comment: qgis2web tries to translate from QGIS style (which can be quite simple to complex in terms of what you can do for styling) into something that works on the web based on the map library that is used.  I suspect you won't get a lot of 1:1 matches.   Source code is here if you want to see how it works

Comment: https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/tree/master/qgis2web

Comment: Thank you for that knowledge! i didn't think about how since its a simple plugin, expecting it to be a 1:1 match is a big ask. I presume there must be a way to fulfill usecase if I modify the original 'style' into something that the plugin understands

Answer (score 3):

As @Nathan W says in his comment, qgis2web tries to translate QGIS styes into webmap styles. qgis2web is a plugin, not written by any core QGIS devs. Nothing it does happens automatically. Every QGIS project layer is queried, each style is inspected, and each symbol layer is investigated.

qgis2web exports in either Leaflet or OpenLayers format. Each of those have their own styling capabilities, as does QGIS itself. Those capabilities are far from identical.

In other words, many style functions from QGIS cannot be represented in Leaflet or OpenLayers. In addition, some which could work have not been implemented, through lack of volunteer time.

It would be good to know more specifically what your requirements are. Since you say it must work locally, does it even have to be a webmap?

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be a webmap but it does need to be interactable. Specifically, move around the map and click on different spots that open data from the attribute table and have some buttons I can use to represent the data and be clickable for the viewer to get more information.

my use case is as follows:

-retain my points and lines shape file layers from my QGIS map
-be able to hover or click on the points to bring up important data
-be able to obfuscate unnecessary data
-make it as easy and fool proof as possible.

Comment: The reason I asked that specific question is that an alternative could be to install QGIS on destination machines. You can vastly simplify the interface to turn it into much more of a map viewer, and that would, by definition, virtually guarantee identical display.

Comment: that would make it amazingly easy but sadly, this is a product I need to be able to deliver to people without any assumptions of skill or software installed. QGIS2web plugin appeals to me because everything is so conveniently packaged and can be sent to anyone

Comment: @Shpoogen Just as an idea, because I dont know enough about it for a qualifying answer: How about using QGIS Web Client together with QGIS-Server or publishing it via QGIS Cloud?